# How do you style span inside a inside div?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've recently added a text tab to a Wordpress menu item by applying span to part of the text, I then styled the content using Console in Chrome.

My problem is selecting the correct element to style so that I can apply my CSS in my websites site-wide settings to make the styling changes I've made permanent.

This is what Console looks like:

[image: View Console Screenshot]

The menu item class ends in .menu-item-4654 so I have tried the following already:

```
span.menu-item-4654 {
    styling: here;
}
```

and

```
menu-item-4654 span {
    styling: here;
}
```

My guess is that because the span is inside an 'a' attribute I am not selecting the correct element to apply the styling.

Can someone please correct this for me?

Comment: `.menu-item-4654 span span { /* do your tricks here */ }` will style NEW

Comment: Thanks Adam and Tim, unfortunately the styling still isn't being applied - here is a screenshot of the styling in my sites custom CSS field: https://s24.postimg.org/aa52qzdo5/Screen_Shot_2017_01_19_at_14_00_16.png

Comment: Are you trying to apply styles to "FEATURES" or to "NEW", or to both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want styling first span:

```
.menu-item-4654 > a > span {
    styling: here;
}
```

if you want styling last span:

```
.menu-item-4654 > a > span > span {
    styling: here;
}
```

Comment: Mario you are the man! Thank you - the solution I needed was styling last span. Much appreciated!

Comment: `menu-item-4654` should be `.menu-item-4654`, there needs to be a `.` as it is a class name.

Comment: A general rule of CSS work is *never be more specific than necessary*. According to this rule the better version of this would be `.menu-item-4654 span span { /* do your tricks here */ }` (which I already commented on your question more than one hour ago). The reason is that this pertains as much flexibility in your markup as possible. An even better way would be to give the inner span a CSS class and simply define styles only for that class (which would make it also independent from the element used).

Answer (score 0):

You're close

```
.menu-item-4654 span{
    styling: here;
}
```

`menu-item-4654` is your list item and your `span` is inside it.

The way you had it setup was you were targeting a `<span class="menu-item-4654">`

Answer (score 0):

Try this path

```
.menu-item-4654 span {
   styling: here;
}
```

Your attempts weren't targeting the right element. Your first attempt was targeting a `span` with class `.menu-item-4654`, there is no such element in the tree.

```
span.menu-item-4654 {
    styling: here;
}
```

The second attempt was missing a dot (you were almost there). Missing that dot means target a tag like

```
<menu-item-4654><!-- inner HTML --></menu-item-4654>
```

Which is not valid by HTML5 standards unless you register them, see [Custom Elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/WD-custom-elements-20161013/).

```
menu-item-4654 span {
styling: here;
}
```

Comment: `menu-item-4654 span { }` cannot be validated using HTML 5 standards since it is CSS. And yes, it is valid CSS. And yes, `<menu-item-4654><!-- inner HTML --></menu-item-4654>` is perfectly valid HTML as well since HTML 5 allows for custom elements.

Comment: @connexo I'm sorry but this is completely wrong. This will not validate with HTML5.

Comment: It is working, and it will soon validate formally. https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/WD-custom-elements-20161013/

Answer (score 0):

You would want to select it via either the general:

```
.menu-item span {
    /* Things */
}
```

Or the more specific (2nd child)

```
.menu .menu-item:nth-child(2) span {
    /* Stuff */
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the closest I've gotten to the effect I'm after, please take a look at this screenshot of what I have now, the issue now is that the styling is being applied to both parts of the menu item, rather than just the content inside the span. (I used the 2nd child version) https://s27.postimg.org/3l9dlkbz7/Screen_Shot_2017_01_19_at_14_11_21.png

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style the span element you've highlighted, use the following CSS selector.

```
.menu-item-4654 > a > span {
    some: property;
}
```

The dot identifies "menu-item-4654" as a class. The greater than sign selects only the children of the parent. You can read the definition [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators).
I would recommend looking up CSS specificity to learn how this works.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @mariobros for providing me with the working solution.

For future reference **the correct answer that fixed my issue was**:

```
menu-item-4654 > a > span > span {
    styling: here;
}
```

Much appreciated!

[View Final Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btwpR.png)

Comment: Since there is no `<menu-item-4654>` element this code will definitely do absolutely nothing.